# how apply a division while streaming a map in java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm streaming and sorting the entries by value, but I also want to divide the value of each entry by a value X.

So I need to convert the value of the Map to Double and apply the division.

I want to do the division before sorting, meaning that it will be sorted by the result of the division.

Currently I have this:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = countMapper.entrySet().stream()
                .map((v) -> v.setValue(v.getValue() / X))
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do the division before sorting? Letting corner cases like infinity or NaN aside, the order is either, the same or reversed if X is negative.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a Tuple2 to save both the "value" and the "value/x", and consume them one by one after.
Here is a sample for you.

```
static class Tuple2<T1, T2>{
    public T1 _1;
    public T2 _2;
    public static <T1, T2> Tuple2<T1, T2> apply(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
        Tuple2<T1, T2> tuple2 = new Tuple2<T1, T2>();
        tuple2._1 = t1;
        tuple2._2 = t2;
        return tuple2;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Integer> countMapper = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int X = 1;
    Map<String, Integer> result = countMapper.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> Tuple2.apply(entry.getKey(), Tuple2.apply(entry.getValue(), entry.getValue() / X )))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt((Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> t) -> t._2._1).reversed())
        .map(t -> Tuple2.apply(t._1, t._2._2))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap((Tuple2<String, Integer> t) -> t._1, t -> t._2, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with your implementation is that your `map` function is attempting to modify an existing `Map.Entry` rather than creating a new one. The `map` function expects you to return new things that represent the result of a transformation on the input, rather than directly modifying the input which won't work with `map`.

So you need to return a new `Map.Entry` rather than modifying the input. Fortunately, Java 9 and later have a handy function `Map.entry` that lets you make a new entry:

```
        countMapper.entrySet().stream()
            .map((entry) -> Map.entry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() / 2))
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue,
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Also, as Preston pointed out in his answer, there's nothing magical about `Map.Entry` here. You could use any other data structure to hold the intermediate data. I like using `Map.Entry` here because it suggests more strongly what the purpose of the `.map` and `.sorted` lines is with respect to the final result -- we're going to halve the entries, and then sort the entries by value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also reuse the java SimpleEntry class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> countMapper = Map.of("Jerry", 7, "Tom", 30);
    double divisor = 5;
    Map<String, Double> result = countMapper.entrySet().stream()
            .map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(v.getKey(), ((double) v.getValue() / divisor)))
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

output

```
{Tom=6.0, Jerry=1.4}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `.map`. Use `.peek`,

```
Map<String, Integer> result = countMapper.entrySet().stream()
                .peek(v -> v.setValue(v.getValue() / X))
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: This is poor form, applies side effects to the initial map, and can fail if the map is unmodifiable or is accessed concurrently.

Comment: what would be the best approach?